# QTableView cell data disapears when the cell is activated

Tags: qt

I'm developing an application using QT5.0 and new to QT. Badly, i have not too much time for a long learning curve.
I have derived my own TableModel and set it to a editable TableView. TableView shows model's data, it works. But when i activate a cell on the tableview, the data disappears. I looked at the documentation and saw that QTableView is derived from QAbstractItemView class which have a signal called 'activated' and a slot called 'edit'. So, i think 'activated' signal is connected to 'edit' slot. But 'edit' is not virtual, so i can not override it. I may connect my child class to parents 'activated' signal but actually i do not know how to handle this signal in order to save the current data of the TableView object.
There is no problem if the code uses SqlTableModel. I think it handles the 'activated' signal but I'm not sure about these, just speculating..
What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Check your the data function:

```
QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    if( !index.isValid() )
        return QVariant();       
    if( role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole) {
        return <your data>
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

Ensure that you process the `EditRole` role.

Good luck!